# Matching an Array to a date in a Function

Tags: php, mysql

I hope somebody can help, I have a class booking system for a gym that displays the weekly timetable. It works perfectly however some weeks a certain detail of the class will change, perhaps the start time or the instructor.

Currently the classes are pulled from the database and stored in an array based on the day of the week and then a function compares the date and displays them in the right place.

I have a table in the database for any changes to a class on a certain date called exceptions.

The structure of both arrays is below:

```
$timetable  [Monday]  [0]  id,  class_name,  min_attendees, max_attendees, start_time, end_time, day, start_date, studio_name, firstname, surname

$exceptions  [1]  exc_class_id, exc_class_date, exc_name, exc_notes, exc_minattendees, exc_maxattendees, exc_price, exc_starttime, exc_endtime, exc_firstname, exc_surname, exc_studio_name
```

The function that displays the classes on the timetable is as follows:

```
 function day_switch ($weekday, $timetable, $fulldate) {

switch($weekday)
 {
    case 'Monday':   
      foreach($timetable['Monday'] as $details) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($weekday));   
        echo "<div class='class'>";
        echo "<a href='" . "templates/viewClass.php?id=" . $details['id'] . "&date=" . $fulldate . "'>" . $details['class_name'] . "</a>";
        echo '<br>';
        echo $details['firstname'] . ' ' . $details['surname'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo $details['start_time'] . ' ' . $details['end_time'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($weekday)); // Replace this with number booked, need to join bookings onto timetable
        echo "</div>";
        }
    break;

    case 'Tuesday':
      foreach($timetable['Tuesday'] as $details) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($weekday));  
        echo "<div class='class'>";
        echo "<a href='" . "templates/viewClass.php?id=" . $details['id'] . "&date=" . $fulldate . "'>" . $details['class_name'] . "</a>";
        echo '<br>';
        echo $details['firstname'] . ' ' . $details['surname'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo $details['start_time'] . ' ' . $details['end_time'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($weekday));
        echo "</div>";
        }
    break;
```

etc....

I need to incorporate into this a check that looks at the exception array and sees whether the class id matches and secondly the current date matches $date.

There is only one record in exceptions per date but there could be multiple for each class id, hence why an SQL join wouldn't work.

If anyone could help I'd be so grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this function inside every foreach loop. This function call should be the **first line inside** the foreach loop.

I hope it helps.

```
function checkException($details, $exceptions){
    foreach($exceptions as $exception){
        if(($exception['exc_class_id'] == $details['id']) && ($exception['exc_class_date'] == $details['start_date']))
            return array(
                'id' => $details['id'],
                'class_name' => $exception['exc_name'],
                'firstname' => $exception['exc_firstname'],
                'lastname' => $exception['exc_lastname'],
                'start_time' => $exception['exc_starttime'],
                'end_time' => $exception['exc_endtime']
                //Add whatever details you want to be changed here...
            );
    }
    return $details;
}
```

Ex.

```
foreach($timetable['Monday'] as $details){
    $details = checkException($details, $exceptions);
    //Rest of the code here below
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do that, it's been a massive help! Very much appreciated!!